# Upload Multiple Files to a FTp server within one session

Tags: c#, upload, ftp

I need to upload multiple files to an ftp server, i tried to send each file a time using Webrequest, the problem is that each time I send a file i need to add credentials , which means i open up a new session. I tried different approach but it didn't work, below my latest. Does anyone have an idea how to do it gracefully? I need to send many files a time using one FTPWebrequest,without connection each time i send a file,please consider that those files are very volumenous . can anyone help me please?

```
 private void envoiFTP(string table)
    {
          string path = @"D:\Temp\";
          string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path,@"*.xml");


          if (files != null)
          {                     
                foreach (string file in files)
                {

                    fi = new FileInfo(file);
                    string fileName = fi.Name;
                    string fileurl = path + @"/" + fileName;
                    string ftpFile = FtpServer + @"/" + fileName;
                    FtpWebRequest myRequest = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpFile);

                    myRequest.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(FtpUser, FtpPassword);

                    myRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
                    myRequest.Timeout = 1000000;
                    myRequest.UseBinary = true;
                    myRequest.KeepAlive = true;


                     myRequest.ContentLength = fi.Length;

                     byte[] buffer = new byte[4097];
                     int bytes = 0;
                     int total_bytes = (int)fi.Length;
                     System.IO.FileStream fs = fi.OpenRead();
                     System.IO.Stream rs = myRequest.GetRequestStream();


                     while (total_bytes > 0)
                     {
                         bytes = fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                         rs.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                         total_bytes = total_bytes - bytes;
                     }

                     fs.Close();
                     rs.Close();

                     FtpWebResponse uploadResponse = (FtpWebResponse)myRequest.GetResponse();
                     uploadResponse.Close();
                }


           } 
                }


            }


    }
```

Comment: @Ramhound that exactly what i want , can u please give me a hand on how to use one ftpwebrequest to send many files ?

Comment: @Ramhound I edited my question i hope it's clear enough now.